# Request for the permission of type ‘InteropPermission’ failed.”. Object can not created

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I want to integrate **com object** in Ax 2009.

I created a DLL with .NET framwork 4.7. Along with CPU architecture as All and strongly signed.
Registered the com object at client machine as it works fine at client machine.

Then I take the same DLL and registered it on the server. But this time I get message.

```
"“Request for the permission of type ‘InteropPermission’ failed.”. Object can not created.
```

[image]

Even its did not work with this piece of code.

```
InteropPermission permission = new InteropPermission( InteropKind::ComInterop ).assert();
myDll dll = new myDll();
```

Error:

```
As compiler comes over as new method in myDll class it throw error.
"“Request for the permission of type ‘InteropPermission’ failed.”. Object can not created.
```

[image]

```
public void new ( Com("{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}"))
{
 ......
}
```

What surprise me most is that same DLL works fine on client machine but gives error on server.
Although it registered along with administrative privilege.

Comment: So this code works `client-side` but not `server-side`?

Comment: is CIL switch `on` or  `off`? can you start a test application on server to create you com object? what is with test app? Note: You can to use powershell, vb, c# fro you test app

Comment: @AlexKwitny. Yes. Its not working server-side.

Comment: @LetsDoGreen Where are you asserting permission? From your stack trace, it looks like it you might be asserting in the `Job`, which is instantiated on the client, then your `new()` method may be instantiating the `COM` object on the server. As a test, try simply creating a method called `initCOM()` and then call it from you `new()` method and wrap the assertion in that newly created method. Try and eliminate some variables.

Comment: @AlexKwitny. You are right. Now i moved the asserting permission statement from job to the class. And hence error **'Request for permission of type..............."** eliminate. But its comes new error. **Com object of class DF269633-D9AA-36F1-B33A-E2FC63B68A86 could not be created. Ensure that the object has been properly registered on computer.Object 'Com' could not be created**

Comment: @LetsDoGreen are you sure it's registered on both the client and server? Have you tried `regsvr32` and maybe putting in `GAC`?

Comment: @AlexKwitny. I had registered the dll with `regasm myddl.dll /tlb:mydll.tlb´ . So i can see my registered typed dll in **COM Class wrapper wizard**. And also keep the dll in the Server/bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are using .NET Framework 4.7 in AX 2009 - as far as I remember AX 2009 can work only with .NET 3.5 DLL's.

Regardless of that, in this piece of code isn't `InteropKind::ClrInterop` needed instead of `InteropKind::ComInterop`?

```
InteropPermission permission = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop).assert();
myDll dll = new myDll();
```

As to the both screenshots from your question, I don't think you are doing `new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop).assert()` there - in fact that wouldn't be possible because `new COM(...)` is in the parameters and not the body of the method. Try moving your code `o = new COM(...)` inside the method after the `new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop).assert()` line.

Comment: You are right. I edit my post regarding ::ClrInterop and move interopPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop).assert() statement within the body.

Comment: Now class new method looks like: void new()
{
    InteropPermission   perm;
    Com                 _com;
    Object              o;

    ;

    perm = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop);
    perm.assert();
    _com = new COM('{DF269633-D9AA-36F1-B33A-E2FC63B68A86}');

Comment: after inserting above code, new error comes "Com object of class 'DF269633-D9AA-36F1-B33A-E2FC63B68A86}' could not be created. Ensure that the object has been properly registered on computer XXXXX. Object 'Com' could not be created.

Comment: @LetsDoGreen, please note that if your original question was resolved and this is a completely new error then you should create a new question rather than update the existing question or try to resolve the new error in the comments. You will also have a higher chance to receive a proper solution. One thing I can suggest is to check maybe your COM object cannot be used by NETWORK SERVICE (there was a similar issue using Word from AX 4.0) but I don't know your system configuration so I'm just guessing here. I suggest you to create a new question if the original question is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Without more hands-on, it's difficult to debug for us. I suggest you update your [Cross Reference (2012 link, but similar in AX09)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877386.aspx), then go to `\System Documentation\Classes\COM\new` and then do a `Used by`:

[image]

Then you'll see a bunch of examples where Microsoft uses and creates a `COM` object that you can model yours against.

**Note** `Used By` will not work until you have updated your cross reference (AKA XRef). Screenshots are from AX 2012.

[image]

Comment: Even if cross-references are not updated then it is quite easy (and also quickly in AX 2009) to search for text '`new COM(`' in the Classes node of the AOT.

Comment: Very true. I usually have mine built.